# Add columns to dataframe that not exist in df1 but exist in df2

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

i want add columns to dataframe1(df1) that not exist in dataframe2(df2) and take value from df2.
for example

```
df1:

A |B |C |
---------
ad|bd|cd|
ss|tt|yy|


df2: (only 1 row)
A|B|C|D|E|F|G|
--------------
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|
```

i want this:

```
df3:
A|B|C|D |E|F|G|
--------------
ad|bd|cd|d|e|f|g|
ss|tt|yy|d|e|f|g|
```

how i can do rapidly?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `df2` has exactly 1 row, you can use `crossJoin` like below:

```python
>>> df1.show()
+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|
+---+---+---+
| ad| bd| cd|
| ss| tt| yy|
+---+---+---+

>>> df2.show()
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|  D|  E|  F|  G|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|  e|  f|  g|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

>>> df3 = df1.crossJoin(df2.drop(*df1.columns))
>>> df3.show()
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|  D|  E|  F|  G|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| ad| bd| cd|  d|  e|  f|  g|
| ss| tt| yy|  d|  e|  f|  g|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Additionally, you could use `df3 = df2.drop(*df1.columns)` to remove the columns of df1 from df2 to reduce the code.

Comment: @gaw thank you for suggestion I updated the code